# Extract date from a variable in a different format

Tags: shell, date, string

Let me explain you the problem

```
$ date +%c -d "$d"
Tue 31 Dec 2013 01:13:06 PM CET
$ date +'Today is %F' -d "$d"
Today is 2013-12-31
```

This solution corresponds to current date.

But I have one variable which stores date other than current date

```
$Prev_date="Wed Dec 25 06:35:02 EST 2013"
```

I am looking for solution to read this date as 2013-12-25 and store it in a variable.

I have tried this:

```
a=`date --date=$Prev_date '+%y/%m/d'`
echo $a
```

It's giving this error:

```
date: illegal option -- date=Wed
usage: date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
date [-u] [+format]
date -a [-]sss[.fff]
```

Comment: Is it possible to call date with a different format string to reach the goal?

Comment: Looks like your version of `date` does not recognize the `--date` option. Why don't you use `-d "$Prev_date"` like your working example? Anyway, please remember to always include your OS. Are you actually on Unix? If so, `date` is very different to the GNU `date` that GNU/Linux uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-d` option is GNU specific.

Here, you don't need to do date calculation, just rewrite the string which already contains all the information:

```
a=$(printf '%s\n' "$Prev_date" | awk '{
  printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\n", $6, \
  (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$2)+2)/3,$3}')
```

Answer (score 10):

I assume you are talking about Bash. If so, then you are missing the `"` around the arguments of the `--date` parameter.

Instead of

```
a=`date --date=$Prev_date '+%y/%m/d'`
```

try this

```
a=`date --date="$Prev_date" '+%y/%m/d'`
```

and I'm guessing the `d` is supposed to have a `%`. So then it would be like that:

```
a=`date --date="$Prev_date" '+%y/%m/%d'`
```

The reasons why your error showed you the usage of the date command is following:

Without the `"` around `$Prev_date`, the variable will be substituted and the command looks like this:

```
a=`date --date=Wed Dec 25 06:35:02 EST 2013 '+%y/%m/d'`
```

So only the `Wed` is taken as argument to `--date`, while all the other parts of the `$Prev_date` string are considered separate parameters to the date command. So date says it doesn't know a parameter called `Dec` and shows you it's help output.

Comment: I am working on ksh and still getting the same error date: illegal option -- date=Mon Dec 30 06:35:02 EST 2013
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]

Comment: Which operating system are you using? It seems your `date` command take different parameter than mine (Gentoo Linux)

Comment: @user3149144 try to replace `date` with `gdate`

Comment: gdate is not working for me. I am using SunOS 5.10

Comment: One minor change, you should try and avoid using the back ticks, use `$(cmd)` now.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand right, you want to save the date, so that you can reuse it later to print the same date in different formats. For this, I propose to save the date in a format that can be easily parsed by the `date -d` command, and let the `date` command do the formatting.

As far as I know, the format `+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S` is the most platform independent. So let's save the date in this format:

```
d=$(date '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Then later you can print this date in different formats, for example:

```
$ date +%c -d "$d"
Tue 31 Dec 2013 01:13:06 PM CET
$ date +'Today is %A' -d "$d"
Today is Tuesday
$ date +'Today is %F' -d "$d"
Today is 2013-12-31
```

**UPDATE**

If you are given a date string like `Wed Dec 25 06:35:02 EST 2013`, then you can try to parse it with `date -d` and change its format, for example:

```
$ date +%F -d 'Wed Dec 25 06:35:02 EST 2013'
2013-12-25
```

This works with GNU date. If it doesn't work in your system, you can try the `gdate` command instead, *usually* it exists in modern systems.

Comment: Thanks for the above answer. But it doesn't solve my issue. Let me explain you the problem

$ date +%c -d "$d"

Tue 31 Dec 2013 01:13:06 PM CET

$ date +'Today is %F' -d "$d"

Today is 2013-12-31

This solution corresponds to correct date. 

But I have one variable which stores date other than correct date
                                                                      
$Prev_date="Wed Dec 25 06:35:02 EST 2013"

I am looking for solution as 2013-12-25 and store it in a variable

Comment: I see. To be honest you didn't explain yourself very well. Now I understand better what you need and updated my answer. Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: I tried the updated code. Output coming is 2013-12-31. I am using SunOS 5.10

Comment: @user3149144 since you are in Solaris try `gdate` instead of `date`. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: gdate is not working for me

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that the date stored in `$C` above is being evaluated before being passed into your subshell (by the use of ``), so the subshell is trying to find a literal command named 'Tue' (i.e. the start of your date string).

To fix this, you'll need to pass your date command back into a GNU version of `date` using the `-d` option, which will take an existing date as input.

I've illustrated this using your example code above:

```
C=$(date)
G=$(gdate '+%Y%m%d' -d "$C")

echo "C = $C"
echo "G = $G"
```

Which outputs

```
C = Tue Dec 31 10:33:29 EST 2013
G = 20131231
```

*Note: I had to use `gdate` to get this to work on my system (OS X).*

If you don't have a GNU compatible `date` command, and can't install it for whatever reason, the best you could do would be to manipulate the date string directly, using something like this:

```
C=$(date)
D=$(echo "$C" | awk -F' ' '{ printf "%s-%s-%s", $6, $2, $3 }')

echo "C = $C"
echo "D = $D"
```

which produces the following output:

```
C = Tue Dec 31 12:03:27 EST 2013
D = 2013-Dec-31
```

Comment: gdate is not working for me, my system is SunOS 5.10

Comment: Are you able to you install it?  Otherwise, I'm afraid SunOS does not have a compatible `date` command for what you're trying to accomplish.  In which case, you'll need to modify the original date format stored in `$C` either by producing it with another `+format`, or by manipulating the string itself.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X using the FreeBSD `date` command you could do the transformation via epoch time:

```
epoch_time="$(LANG=C TZ='EST' date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "Wed Dec 25 06:35:02 EST 2013" "+%s")"
a="$(date -r $epoch_time '+%F')
echo "$a"  #  2013-12-25
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the first output is G. `C` already contains the first word of the actual date (Tue), so when you try to execute

```
`tue …format… `
```

your shell answers that tue is not a valid command.

```
$ A=date
$ echo $($A)
Mar 31 déc 2013 12:21:48 CET
$ B=$($A)   
$ echo $B
Mar 31 déc 2013 12:22:12 CET
```

Try just storing date in your `C` variable, as I did with `A`.

And by the way, can't you find better names for them?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to store the exact time, using GNU date, I have found the following options can output in a format that `date` is happy to parse again:

```bsh
date -R
date --iso-8601=ns         # <-- JavaScript's new Date() does not parse this one
date --iso-8601=seconds
date --rfc-3339=ns
date --rfc-3339=seconds
```

Note that only the `ns` options record nanoseconds (although most filesystems only store seconds anyway).

(Out of interest, I also tested them in Node.JS and in Firefox, and only the one indicated failed to parse.)

For example, to read the date of a file into a variable, and then parse and display it:

```bsh
# Record when bash was compiled into a variable
prev_date="$(date --rfc-3339=ns -r /bin/bash)"

# Parse the variable and display in desired format
echo "Date is: $(date -d "$prev_date" '+%y/%m/%d')"
```

What I would like to know now: How to do the same with BSD `date`?