# use one date variable but format it different ways

Tags: timestamps

In a shell script, there are the following variables:
`datestamp=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_T%H-%M-%S')`
`datestamp_pretty=$(date '+%m/%d/%Y at %I:%M:%S %p')`

The first one is used as part of the output filename while the second one is used to display a nicely readable date and time in the contents of the file.  Since these are created separately, the seconds can be off slightly.  Is there a way to create a single date variable and then format it two different ways?  If so, how is this done?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107290/extract-date-from-a-variable-in-a-different-format

Comment: That's not a duplicate. Here, a better approach would be something like `eval "$(date +"datestamp='%Y-%m-%d_T%H-%M-%S' datestamp_pretty='%m/%d/%Y at %I:%M:%S %p'")"` and avoid relying on that `-d` GNU extension.

Comment: Note that that `datestamp_pretty` format of yours is US-specific and would generally not work properly outside a US or C/POSIX locale. Using `%c` is probably better for a human-readable date adapted to the user's locale.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas How would `%c` be used in `datestamp_pretty` to replace the code that's there but yield the same output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy if you are using GNU `date`.

First, get the most generic time format from `date`.  I chose to get the epoch time:

```
epoch=$(date +%s)
```

Then, convert the epoch into whatever format you want however many times you want:

```
datestamp=$(date -d @$epoch '+%Y-%m-%d_T%H-%M-%S')
datestamp_pretty=$(date -d @$epoch '+%m/%d/%Y at %I:%M:%S %p')
```

It should always represent the time when you first captured `$epoch`.

If you do not have GNU `date`, you would need some other method of converting the epoch to a human date.

Comment: In `@$epoch`, what does the `@` do?

Comment: According to [this `coreutils` example page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html), it is shorthand to represent `date -d "1970-01-01 UTC $epoch seconds"`

Comment: The "`@`" should make you read `man date`.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a way to do it that doesn't require GNU `date`
and doesn't require you to run `date` more than once.

Pick a string that will never appear in any of the date/time strings. 
It can be a single character — for example, `~`, `^` and `|` would all work. 
But I’ll demonstrate with `/foo/`.

Simply concatenate your date string formats
with your chosen string between them. 
(Remove the `+` from the second format.) 
Capture the output from `date` into a variable,
and then split it at your delimiter string:

```
combined=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_T%H-%M-%S/foo/%m/%d/%Y at %I:%M:%S %p')
datestamp="${combined%/foo/*}"
datestamp_pretty="${combined#*/foo/}"
```

Comment: Yes. Exactly this